# Google Play Games iOS SDK for multiplatform real time

Tags: ios, google-play-games, multiplatform

I'm trying to use Google Play Games for implement a multiplatform multiplayer real time game.
I've follow all the instructions in https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/realtimeMultiplayer the sign in, random room creation, sending invites and sending messages between players are all working correctly. But I'm stuck on leaving the room when the iOS player goes in background and the other one is on an Android device.
In my `applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:` method I'm doing the following piece of code

```
[self.currentRoom leave];
self.matchStarted = NO;
self.currentRoom = nil;
```

and in my `room:didChangeStatus:` I'm correctly receive the `GPGRealTimeRoomStatusDeleted` status; the problem is that the Android device is not receiving anything, so the game hung on a state where the iOS part is successfully disconnected from the room and the Android one thinks that all the players are connected and alive.
What I'm doing wrong?
If two Android devices are playing together and one of them call the leaving method they successfully disconnect both from the room so the problem lies in the iOS implementation.

Comment: Curious. We encountered a similar problem a while ago, but haven't seen it since. What happens with version 2.0.1 of the SDK? Does that fix this issue? (We added a number of multiplayer fixes to that version.)

Comment: We update the SDK to the last version, the problem persist but in a different way. Now when the app goes in background the opponent still don't receive nothing, but as soon as the other app resume the activity it receive the correct notification that the opponent left the room; if we wrap the calls insite the beginBackgroundTask and endBackgroundTask the behavior remain the one before the SDK update, in which the opponent never receive anything at all.